# Is there any difference between sufficient statistics for known and unknown distribution parameters?

Tags: self-study, inference, beta-distribution, sufficient-statistics

I wonder if there is any difference between sufficient statistics for known and unknown distribution parameters.

For example, let us take $Beta(a,b)$ distribution. If we use Fisher-Neyman theorem, we can easily evaluate the sufficient statistics $\prod x$ and $\prod (1-x)$. However, as far as I understand this, this is for unknown parameters $a,b$.

If $a,b$ were known, would the result differ? If would, can you give a hint how?

Comment: If a parameter is _known_, it is fixed and no longer a parameter, hence the notion of sufficiency does not apply to this parameter. If all parameters are known, all statistics are sufficient and the notion is moot.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. What if only one "parameter" is know, while the other is unknown (say, b).

Comment: Yes, but what happens in the particular case of Beta distribution with only parameter $b$?

Comment: Am I right that in this particular case with Beta distribution, the answer is $\prod (1-x)$ (so we reduced $\prod x$ by looking at Fisher -Neyman )? However, If we took some other distribution, the number of elements insufficient statistics could stay the same?

Comment: I presume you mean $\prod_i(1-x_i)$, which is a sufficient statistic then. Obviously, the sufficient statistic and its dimension vary from one model to the next. A collection of distributions sharing this statistic as sufficient is$$h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\psi(\prod_i(1-x_i);b)$$